# In python: splinter, how can I .click() on un-endorsed linkedin skills?

Tags: python, splinter

**Previous research**

I haveve read the splinter help docs and searched Stack Overflow and spent about 4 hours trying various ideas, mainly playing with dir() in combination with firefox's "inspect element" feature. No success.

**Question**

I am struggling to figure out how I can automatically endorse skills of my connections in Linkedin, restricting the interaction to skills that are **not yet endorsed**. To the Human eye, such skills are presented with a **grey cross** as opposed to a **blue cross** had that skill already been endorsed.

[image]

Comment: Surely the trickier bit would be writing the code to determine whether or not you know if they're any good at that skill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `.click()` on the `<a class="endorse-button" role="button" href="javascript:void(0)">` element of a given skill.

You can filter the skills that are not yet endorsed by checking if there is **"endorsable"** in a parent element of the button element (mentioned above) has `class="endorse-item has-endorsements endorsable"`. Specifically: `<li class="endorse-item has-endorsements endorsable" data-endorsed-item-name="Molecular Biology">`.

The string **"endorsable"** is what separates un-endorsed skills from endorsed ones, for example, already endorsed skills appear as: `<li class="endorse-item has-endorsements endorsed-by-viewer" data-endorsed-item-name="genetics">`; where instead of **"endorsable"** you have the string **"endorsed-by-viewer"**.

The code required to filter, then click on endorsable skills is thus:

```
##############################################################
# Searches for the "endorse skills" buttons and iteratively clicks them...
##############################################################

list_of_skills = browser.find_by_id("profile-skills")[0].find_by_css("li")

for skill in list_of_skills:

    if skill.has_class("endorse-item has-endorsements endorsable"):

        # ...this skill can be endorsed

        button_and_other = skill.find_by_css("div")[0].find_by_css("a") # there are two elements that match "a": [0] list of endorsers, [1] the endorse button

        for css in button_and_other:

            if css.has_class("endorse-button"): # ..if the element has the class: "endorse-button" we click it

                css.click()
    else:

        # ...this skill is already endorsed

        pass
```